# When does this integral converge? $\;\;\int_0^\infty {\frac{e^{-ax}}{x^2+1}}\,\mathrm{d}x$

Tags: calculus, integration, convergence-divergence

$$\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-ax}}{x^2+1}\,\mathrm{d}x$$  - $a$ real, for which a does this converge? (The final answer is $a\ge 0$)

I've tried doing this by parts and it seems to work at first, but then everything cancels and I get $0=0$ at the 2nd passage. I can't come up with any manipulations, any hints?
Thanks.

Comment: If you only have to show convergence, why don't you use an estimate? Note that $(x^2+1)^{-1}\leq1$

Comment: Wow, so many answers and so fast, thanks for your help everyone.

Comment: @Zero, if you like an answer you are supposed to upvote by clicking on up arrow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $a=0$ then evaluating the integral is routine.

If $a>0$ then we have $\displaystyle \int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-ax}}{x^2+1}\le\int_0^\infty e^{-ax}\,dx$, and that converges, so the original integral converges by comparison.

If $x<0$ then $\dfrac{e^{-ax}}{x^2+1}\to\infty$ as $x\to\infty$, so the integral diverges.

You're main mistake is trying to actually evaluate the integral.  You don't need to do that in order to answer the question.

Comment: nice answer. even in the case $a = 0,$ you can use $\frac{1}{1+x^2} < \frac{1}{x^2}$ and argue $\int_0^\infty \frac{dx}{x^2}$ converges.

Comment: @abel : That won't work, because although $\int_1^\infty dx/x^2<\infty$, you will find that $\int_0^1 dx/x^2=\infty$. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: i was only looking at $\infty$ and forgot the singularity at $0.$ at $0$ the integral has no singularity to begin with but introduced one. i got you.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

- For $a\ge0$ we have

$$\frac{e^{-ax}}{1+x^2}\le \frac1{1+x^2}\in L^1(0,\infty)$$
and

- For $a<0$ we have

$$\frac{e^{-ax}}{1+x^2}\ge x,\quad\text{for $x$ sufficently large}$$

Comment: what would a calculus student know about $L^1(0, \infty)?$

Answer (score 0):

If $a<0$, $\frac{e^{-ax}}{x^2+1} \to \infty$ as $x \to \infty$ and hence the given integral diverges.

When $a \geq 0$   $$\frac{e^{-ax}}{x^2+1} \leq \frac{1}{x^2+1} \qquad 0 < x < \infty$$

The integral of right side of the inequality converges and hence the given integral converges when $a \geq 0$